# Resin Server Exception

Tags: java, resin

What would be the possible causes for the below exception on resin server restart?

500 Servlet Exception
conf/resin.conf:168: java.lang.StackOverflowError

---

Resin Professional 3.0.21 (built Thu, 10 Aug 2006 12:17:46 PDT)

Comment: I don't have an idea. Paste resin.conf line 168, probably the answer resides there.

Comment: The full stack trace may help too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was happening because there was no enough disk space in the server for the app server to get started. When I freed the logs there server got up.

Answer (score 0):

Circular element reference in your conf?